# Use Liquibase on SQL introspection generated Hibernate classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-migration, liquibase

I would like to know if I can easily use Liquibase on SQL introspection generated Hibernate classes.  I inherited a Spring 4, Hibernate 5 project and am somewhat unfamiliar with Java Hibernate best practices.

All the entity classes seem to be generated from hbm2java by SQL inspection. This is inferred by an absence of any hibernate mapping files, but hbm2java created all entity files.

I would like to keep the directionality that entity classes are generated by the databases, but have schema migrations owned by the application through Liquibase or similar.  Is this an easy pattern to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I use two maven goals in `process-resources` phase.

1. Liquibase
2. Hibernate hbm2java

I tried hsqldb on `target/mydatabase` unfortunately if the first goal (liquibase) finished its not flushed to the file and the second goal has a empty database. Finally i use h2database on `jdbc:h2:file:./target/mydatabase...`. It works like a charm.

Comment: "It works like a charm".... see, iv noticed on mysql the liquibase-type `"long"` creates different types and different entitys accoring to what database you use. h2 for example creates a `number` but mysql creates a `text` type row.